# How do I save a string of numbers from an ongoing command to a list in a shell script?

Tags: linux, command-line, shell-script, sh

I am trying to make a shell script for recording macros via recording the individual keycodes of each button press.

The command for it looks like this:

```
xev | grep -A2 --line-buffered '^Key*' | sed -n '/keycoe /s/^.*keycode \([0-9]*\).* (.*, \(.*\)).*$/\1 /p'
```

You can run it in the terminal to see how it works.

Basically what it does is spit out a ton of number codes (keycodes) with line spaces between each one like this:

```
51
51
42
42
53
30
30
53
```

And so on and so forth. I need to capture every one of those codes individually, and place them into a list/string that will look something like this:

```
xdotool keydown 51 && xdotool keyup 51 && xdotool keydown 42 && xdotool keyup 42
```

And on it goes. (everytime a number pops up it is assigned as keydown, everytime it pops up a second time it is read as a keyup to avoid loops)

How can I make this happen in a shell script? How can I make a shell script take each individual keycode when it occurs, and save it to a variable?

The script on it's own is easy enough, but I have no idea how to get the individual codes, since the only thing that separates the codes is a line break.

Comment: `| while read kk; do echo "xdotool keydown $kk && xdotool keyup $kk &&"; done; echo true`

Comment: thanks mpez0, that looks good. But what I really need is how to define kk correctly.

Comment: did you notice the pipe character in the front? Just add on the end of your xev pipeline

Comment: Oh, I've got it now, thanks! If you add it as an answer, I will mark it as a correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
| while read kk; do echo "xdotool keydown $kk && xdotool keyup $kk &&"; done; echo true
```

Note the pipe in front; this goes on the end of whatever OP uses to generate the xev output described